# Issues with conditional Minimising

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm just starting out with Matlab and am having trouble with optimising a function within constraints.

This is the function, where `lord` is just an `iid` set of random variables.

```
F = @(l) 1/size(Lord,1)*sum(Lord<=l)
```

So I'm trying to minimize this with the condition that `F(l)>=alpha`.

I'm thinking along the lines of

```
[xmin fmin] = fminbnd(F,-1,1)
```

but I'm not sure how to include the condition.

Comment: I think you need to use [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) together with the  non-linear condition `nonlcon`.  Or as your function is rather simple you could just make it yourself using a [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know the `l` where 'F(l)' is smallest but larger than 'alpha'? Easiest is maybe but a huge penalty for values below `alpha`.

```
function y = F(l)
   y = 1/size(Lord,1)*sum(Lord<=l);
   y = y + (y > alpha) * 1e9; % the penalty term
end
```

Put this as function directly before the minimization because Lord and alpha must be withing scope.